# Algo not working for String Decode Ways -- , leetcode 91. --I need output of solutions and not count. Code Attached

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

So I solved this problem of leetcode using dyanmic programming --> https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways/

However ran into trouble while solving a smililar problem given in the image below. We need to actually print all string decodes instead of counting them, I made a code on this attached below, but it doesnt work for any string longer than size 2. What am i doing wrong ??
[image]

```
package MiscStringQs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class printDecodeWays {
    static String str;
    static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
        System.out.println(decodeString());
    }
    
    public static void input() {
        str  = sc.next();
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<String> decodeString() {
        if(str.charAt(0)=='0') {
            ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<>(); ans.add("");
            return ans;
        }
        if(str.length()==1) {
            ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<>(); ans.add(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)+48));
            return ans;
            
        }
        int N = str.length();

        char scan; 
        
        ArrayList <String> ans1 = new ArrayList<>(); //ans1.add("");
        ArrayList <String> ans2 = new ArrayList<>(); //ans2.add("");
        ArrayList <String> prevAns = new ArrayList<>(); prevAns.add("");
        
        String fetch = Character.toString(str.charAt(0)+48); //convert number to alphabet mapping
        ans1.add(fetch);
        String tempStr;

        char prev=str.charAt(0); 

        for(int i=2;i<=N;i++) {
            int strIndex = i-1; 
            scan  = str.charAt(strIndex);
            
            if(scan != '0') {
                for(int j=0;j<ans1.size();j++) {
                     tempStr = ans1.get(j) + Character.toString(scan+48);
                     ans2.add(j, tempStr);
                    
                    if(ans1.size()>4) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            
            }
            if( checkNo(prev,scan) <=26 ) {
                
                for(int j=0;j<prevAns.size();j++) {
                    
                    String comboStr =  Character.toString(prev)+ Character.toString(scan);
                    int comboInt = Integer.parseInt(comboStr);
                    char comboChar = (char) (comboInt + 96);
                    
                    tempStr = prevAns.get(j) + Character.toString(comboChar);
                    ans2.add(tempStr);
        
                }   
            }
            
            prevAns = (ArrayList<String>) ans1.clone();
            ans1= (ArrayList<String>) ans2.clone();
            prev = scan; 
        }
        
        return ans2; 
    }
    
    public static int checkNo(char prev,char scan) {
        return 10* (prev-'0') + (scan-'0');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example "1125" you first take the last number 5, get the character 'e', now your string is "e", With that string in hand recurse on the remaining number "112".
Similarly take the last two numbers 25, get the character 'y', now your string is "y", with that string in hand recurse on the remaining number "11".

Be careful about j = 10 while recursing.

The code will be:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        getAllStrings(list, 1125, "");
        System.out.println(list);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        getAllStrings(list, 10101, "");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    
    private static void getAllStrings(List<String> list, int n, String s) {
        if ( n == 0 ) {
            return;
        } else if ( n < 11 ) {
           list.add(String.valueOf((char)(96+n)) + s);
        } else if ( n < 27 ) {
           list.add(String.valueOf((char)(96+n)) + s);
           if ( n % 10 != 0 ) {
                getAllStrings(list, n/10, String.valueOf((char)(96+n%10)) + s);
            }
        } else {
            if ( n % 10 != 0 ) {
                getAllStrings(list, n/10, String.valueOf((char)(96+n%10)) + s);
            }
           if (( n - n % 10) % 100 != 0 ) {
               getAllStrings(list, n/100, String.valueOf((char)(96+n%100)) + s);
           }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[kbe, aabe, ale, ky, aay]
[jja]
```

Comment: thanks a good solution but as I said I was looking for DP solution